# Taking Intersection of 2 Intervals

Tags: c++, overflow

I have two ranges. One fixed `Start,End`. One is calculated in for loop and I change the the interval according to some conditions.

Basically I want to print the cardinality of the set obtained from intersection between Intervals `[Start,End]` and `[MIN,MAX]` if it exists.

```
#define INF numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
unsigned long long MAX= INF;
unsigned long long MIN=0;
for(;;)
{
   // conditions
   MAX=max(MAX,variable1);
   MIN=min(MIN,variable2);
}
cout<<(min(MAX,End)-max(MIN,Start) +1);
```

Now the problem is when there is no intersection, the answer is some very big  integer. Where as if the intersection between Interals [Start,End] and [MIN,MAX] doen't exist and it should print 0.

I think the problem is due to overflow or/and related to `INF` datatype(double) and variables datatypes(unsigned long long).

How can I rectify it ?

Comment: you have to check if they overlap at all

Comment: @tobi303 Yeah I realized it too. I'm doing it now. Thanks